# How to click the icon using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, webautomation

I am trying to automate my certain activities using selenium. I was launching a webpage and a security windows popup appears for the login credentials.

I have automated that using Autoit. Now after login I need to click on the option and I have tried it based on the find_element_by_text and find_element_by_id.

I was getting an error as Unable to find the element with CSS selector and I have seen some other post in the StackOverflow with the same issue but I could not able to fix it by myself.

Here is how my HTML looks like. Could you please guide me on this and also please share any document for further checking. Thanks.

```
    driver = webdriver.Ie(r"C:\\IEDriverServer\\IEDriverServer.exe")
    driver.get('URL of the page')
    #driver.implicitly_wait(10)  # seconds
    autoit.win_wait("Windows Security")
    # now make that crap active so we can do stuff to it
    autoit.win_activate("Windows Security")
    # type in the username
    autoit.send('username')
    # tab to the password field
    autoit.send("{TAB}")
    # type in the password
    autoit.send('password')
    # kill!
    autoit.send("{ENTER}")
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.implicitly_wait(120)  # seconds
    #submit_button_incidents = driver.find_element_by_link_text("3-Normal Incidents")
    submit_button_incidents= driver.find_element_by_id("nodeImgs13pm")
    submit_button_incidents.click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
```

++ updating the info

I have tried to copy the whole HTML but the page was restricted so I cant able to view the full HTML page other than the basic templates. Adding some more screenshots of the developer tools.

[image]

Here how my webpage looks like.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: consider adding HTML instead of screenshot/images.

Comment: Link text won't work because it's not anchor tag

Comment: Click on which `option`? Only the `span` and `img` tags are visible in the snapshot

Comment: @DebanjanB - Need to click that My Group's Queue. Which will show (expand) some drop down with some other options

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

try with this **code** :

```
submit_button_incidents = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'My Group'])")))  
submit_button_incidents.click()
```

and do not use implicit wait too many times in code.

Implicit wait is set for life time of web driver instance.

**Reference :**

[Selenium official document for wiats](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits)
[Xpath tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
[cssSelector tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_syntax.asp)

**UPDATE :**

As OP has shared the HTML code. As per the requirement you can go ahead with this code.

As there are two elements with text as My Groups's queue.

For first one you can write XPATH as :

```
//a[@class='scbdtext']/span[contains(text(),'My Group')]
```

**Code:**

```
submit_button_incidents = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='scbdtext']/span[contains(text(),'My Group')]")))  
submit_button_incidents.click()
```

For second one you can write XPATH as :

```
//a[@class='scbdtextfoc']/span[contains(text(),'My Group')]
```

**Code :**

```
submit_button_incidents = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='scbdtextfoc']/span[contains(text(),'My Group')]")))  
submit_button_incidents.click()
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have tried the above example it was not working. Getting TimeoutException: Message. I think the click condition is giving false as the value is None. I have tried updatating the text to the full as in the webpage still getting the same. I will update the HTML to the question.

Comment: when you inspect this //span[contains(text(),'My Group']) , how many entries are present ?

Comment: There is few more My group in the HTML page so I have added the whole text also and getting the same result. Thanks.

Comment: @Vignesh : I can see two My group's queue. which one you want to select ? and please  add html in text format so that it'll be easy for us to copy and provide you the solution.

Comment: @Vignesh : Check out my updated answer under UPDATE section. Hope that will be helpful. Thanks !

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. I will try again with your updated suggestions and will let you know

Comment: @Vignesh : Sure bud.

Answer (score 0):

Use ActionChains with double click for this to work in Python.

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
# Get the element however you want
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='scbdtextfoc']/span[contains(text(),'My Group')]")
ActionChains(driver).double_click(settings_icon).perform()
```